# How do I enter a query with a PREFIX in RDF4J Console?

Tags: rdf4j

```
sparql> PREFIX ab: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#>
Executing update...
Update executed in 160 ms
sparql> SELECT ?craigEmail WHERE { ?person ab:firstName "Craig" }
Malformed query: org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.parser.sparql.ast.VisitorException: 
QName 'ab:firstName' uses an undefined prefix

sparql> SELECT ?craigEmail WHERE { ?person 
<http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook/firstName> "Craig" }
Evaluating SPARQL query...
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| craigEmail                                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
0 result(s) (64 ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the prefix on the same line as the query (so everything is on one line).

Answer (score 1):

The RDF4J console by default only takes a single-line SPARQL query, so like James suggested in his answer: enter the query as a single line.

Alternatively, you can use the `sparql` command to enter into multiline mode:

```
memory> sparql
enter multi-line SPARQL query (terminate with line containing single '.')
PREFIX ab: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#>
SELECT ?craigEmail WHERE { ?person ab:firstName "Craig" }
.
Evaluating SPARQL query...
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| craigEmail                                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
0 result(s) (93 ms)
memory>
```

This is particularly useful when you're copy-pasting larger queries.

As an aside, the first "query" that you do:

```
sparql> PREFIX ab: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#>
Executing update...
Update executed in 160 ms
```

The output is misleading, since 'Update executed' suggests you've just added the new namespace prefix. But that's not what's happening. Instead, the console interprets this as a SPARQL update that's missing a "body", and just executes it as an empty update. The prefix is ignored. Arguably this is a fault in the SPARQL parser as just a prefix declaration without a body is, strictly speaking, not a legal query.

There is no "official" way to add a new namespace prefix to an RDF4J store via the Console, but there is a trick you can use (though this will only work if you're executing it on a store or SPARQL endpoint to which you have write access):

```
PREFIX ab: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#> INSERT DATA {}
```

This will execute a SPARQL update to insert new triples, but with an empty block (so no actual triples are inserted). However, this *will* add the namespace prefix to the repository, after which you no longer have to declare it for every query you enter into the console:

```
memory> show n
--no namespaces found--
memory> PREFIX ab: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#> INSERT DATA {}
Executing update...
Update executed in 3 ms
memory> show n
+----------
|ab  http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#
|rdf  http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#
|owl  http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#
|xsd  http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#
|fn  http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#
|rdfs  http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#
|sesame  http://www.openrdf.org/schema/sesame#
+----------
memory> SELECT ?craigEmail WHERE { ?person ab:firstName "Craig" }
Evaluating SPARQL query...
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| craigEmail                                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
0 result(s) (47 ms)
memory>
```